# GXT3 Remove tab from a tabpanel/tab container

Tags: java, tabs, gxt

I am using GXT3 version. I have a screen with tabs where on the first tab I have add button which opens new tab where I do certain functions. After done I need to close the newly opened tab on click of close button which I am not able to do.
To add the new tab I am doing this

```
tabPanel.add(childPanel, new TabItemConfig("some title"));
```

where childPanel is a verticalLayoutContainer widget of another class. The close button is in this another class.

How can I remove this new tab?

Answer (score 2):

if I understood your problem, in gxt3 you need pass in the config if your new tab can be closed.

```
TabItemConfig tabItemConfig = new TabItemConfig("Some Title");
tabItemConfig.setClosable(true);
tabPanel.add(childPanel, tabItemConfig);
```

So the new tab has a close button.